# Deploy Lens Dashboard within K8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, microservices, dashboard

I need to manage a federation of clusters (KubeFed), so I was wondering if it's possible to deploy Lens Dashboard within the cluster?
Otherwise is there any alternative dashboad with multi cluster support within cluster?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).